# Equivalent to the Java "static" keyword in Ceylon

Tags: java, static, ceylon

I wondered if the Ceylon programming language features an equivalent to the "static" keyword in Java, or if there's some common idiom that's used in its place.

Edit: elaborating on the answer, here's an example of a scoped "function" (its syntax is identical to a method) that can be invoked without a class instance, in other words it's just like a static Java method.  Notice the key difference is that this is defined inside an "object" instead of a "class", which effectively makes a singleton with no need to instantiate:

```
object mystaticstuff {
    shared void introduceYourself() {
        print "madam, im adam";
    }
}
```

Note you could also declare the method/function outside of any class or object, in which case it just floats freely in your "global" (still scoped to your package) namespace.

Comment: I think it would be better to have your "edit" as part of the answer, not the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no static members in Ceylon. Rather there are toplevel functions, declared in the package.

More about it here : [Ceylon Docs](http://www.ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.0/spec/html_single/#topleveldeclarations)

Answer (score 4):

We're introducing `static` members in Ceylon 1.3.1.

There's some more information on [this issue](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon/issues/6515).